# LINQ TO SQL or Entity Framework 4 Code-First for a domain driven project?

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework-ctp5

At the actual time, what would be better to use for a domain driven project ?

LINQ TO SQL or Entity Framework 4 Code-First ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all EF CTP5 released last  6th December, link is [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/12/14/ef-feature-ctp5-released.aspx)

We changed our projects repositories and services on CTP5. It is working fine. We are working on 3. sprint of our projects and there is no any issue.

I strongly recommend CTP5 for DDD, and also for any other types of projects.